# How to connect a grails service and javascript code in the view

Tags: javascript, grails

I'm developing a grails plugin that is supposed to be a visual front end for a larger application. The communication from the application to the plugin will be message-driven, and as far as see it, the right way to do it is to receive the messages in a grails service.

Considering there will be several different message types, and that they will influence different parts of the view (which is mostly built around javascript libraries, such as jQuery, jQueryUI, flot and others), I'm not sure how exactly to implement the decision making (which message should update which part of the view), and how to connect the stuff that happens in the service to the javascript code in the view.

**In a nutshell:**

Where to implement the decision making for messages, and how to intelligently connect the grails service with the javascript code in the view.

P.S. I couldn't find a similar question already, and forgive me if the questions are "simple", I'm trying to absorb a lot of new technologies at the same time, and I don't have much time to do it properly.

Comment: A couple of questions: when and how do you want to redraw the view. Is it going to be AJAX-driven? Do you plan to perform some poll/push type communication?

Comment: Feels too generic to me. Highly depends on the intensity and function of messages. Can you please give a couple of specific examples?

Comment: @julkiewicz Interval-based refresh is also acceptable. The ideal solution would be a refresh every time a new message appears, however, automatic refresh every few seconds is just fine too.

Comment: @Victor, the server is crunching some data, and every now and then, it sends a message to the service. Depending on the message type, a different graph (flot library) in the view should be updated. So, different message types should change different parts of javascript and html code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Services can't render views.  And they shouldn't.  That is the job of the Controller.  See [MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller).  Message driven systems generally don't deliver messages for view rendering.  Messages are sent so that the backend can be updated, etc.  So here are some options...

Rethink your message driven approach.  If you continue down this path, you'll need to implement some sort of push ([comet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29)) technology so that the service can notify the client via this push technology that something has changed and needs to be updated.

You could go with an ajax approach and implement polling (carefully) or still use a push (comet) technology.

Go cutting edge and look into [WebSockets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSockets).

Comment: unfortunately, message driven approach is neither my choice, and neither in my power to change. I have to work with what I have, so I'm looking for ideas how to handle the situation I'm currently in. I'll look into the push technology.

Also, I'm not looking to render the view from a service, but rather to send some info from the service to the view and somehow update a javascript array that contains the information for the flot library, and decide which graph should be updated depending on the message sent.

Comment: Rendering the view from the service and sending info to the view is the same thing.  It can't (and shouldn't) be done from the service.  As far as I know, using some push technology or ajax polling is going to be your only option.  However, if someone else has a better idea, I'd be excited to hear about it.

Comment: I wouldn't say that "rendering view and sending info to the view is same thing". If the message sent is "model part N updated", and Controller's responsibility at rendering View remains - it's fine with MVC. Other then that, I'd second the answer.